# Concatenated PDU Flash message

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, modem, pdu

I'm trying to send concatenated flash messages using a sim900 gsm module. Both messages are sent successfully, but I can see only one on my cell phone.

These are the PDUs I'm using:

> AT+CMGS=140
>   pdu part 1 =
>   0051000B916998775706F80010A78F050003790201622C908C059AB1403416A8C602D958A01B0B84638172A0B09B0C8AC158A0188C058AC558A0988C058ACD58A0188D058AD558A0988D058ADD58A0188E058AE55820198C0592C55820998C0592CD5820198D0592D55820998D0592DD5820198E0592E558A0198C059AC558A0998C059ACD58A0198D059AD500
>
> AT+CMGS=43
>   pdu part 2 =
>   0051000B916998775706F80010A72105000379020258A0998D1593CD6839582E3683E564331C2C17C3C96630

Is there something wrong with the UDH? I'm able to send concatenated SMS, but not Flash messages. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a restriction that a flash message length can only be 140 at max?